# Swift extension with extension

Tags: ios, swift

So I want to do something like:

```
protocol CanShowView: class where Self: UIViewController, SomeDelegate{
func someFunction()
}

extension CanShowView{
func someFunction(){
someView.SomeDelegate = self
}
```

Basically, I want to make sure that the protocol can only be implemented by a UIViewController that also implements the SomeDelegate protocol, but xcode is mad about the first line of code in the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Swift 4+ :

```
protocol CanShowView {
    func someFunction()
}

extension CanShowView where Self: UIViewController & SomeDelegate {
    func someFunction() {
        someView.SomeDelegate = self
    }
}
```

If Swift 3.0:

```
protocol CanShowView {
    func someFunction()
}

extension CanShowView where Self: UIViewController, Self: SomeDelegate {
    func someFunction() {
        someView.SomeDelegate = self
    }
}
```

This is the right way to add conditional extensions, not in protocol definition. If you want to limit protocol to some constraint, best way to go is using `associatedType`s.